# Heroku deployment

Tags: heroku

Please can someone tell me what Heroku actually is ? I read that it is a cloud based web server for app deployment , but what does that mean . What can i deploy there , what should / should'nt deploy there . I know it's pretty easy to deploy a nodejs app there . But is it the same for static websites for exemple. Should i deploy bootstrap only project there ? Can i actually do that ? Can i deploy Laravel project on Heroku ? When should i use it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What Heroku is ?**
Heroku is a platform as a service (PaaS) that enables developers to build, run, and operate applications entirely in the cloud.

**What does that mean ?**
It means you can you can deploy your Web Application on their server and use their resources to host your website.

**What can you deploy there ?**
It supports most of the platforms for hosting your Web Application like Node JS, Python, Go lang, Ruby etc. You can check that on their [website](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps)

**Why shouldn't you use it professionally ?**
It's expensive than it's competitors like AWS.

**Is it same for static website ?**
Well actually heroku doesn't support hosting basic websites consisting of only HTML, CSS and JS. But there are some ways in which you can trick heroku into thinking our website is a PHP app. [Here's some more info about it.](https://medium.com/@adityaniloi/how-to-deploy-a-static-website-to-heroku-49d55e07cb94)

**Can you deploy Laravel project on Heroku ?**
Yes you can do that. [Here's the guide on deploying Laravel on heroku.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel)